# Groupby Date and Class and Cumulative Sum - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Category  |  Date      |  Val1  |  Val2  |  Val3  |
----------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
  A       | 2022-01-01 |  50    |   70   |   80   |
  B       | 2022-01-01 |  30    |   50   |   20   |
  C       | 2022-01-01 |  40    |   60   |   90   |
  A       | 2022-01-05 |  10    |   40   |   20   |
  B       | 2022-01-05 |  40    |   75   |   80   |
  C       | 2022-01-05 |  60    |   45   |   65   |
  A       | 2022-01-10 |  50    |   40   |   35   |
  B       | 2022-01-10 |  50    |   50   |   25   |
  C       | 2022-01-10 |  50    |   95   |   85   |
```

What I want to achieve is groupby date and class and take the cumulative sum. So expected output would be like this:

```
Category  |  Date      |  Val1  |  Val2  |  Val3  |
----------|------------|--------|--------|--------|
  A       | 2022-01-01 |  50    |   70   |   80   |
  B       | 2022-01-01 |  30    |   50   |   20   |
  C       | 2022-01-01 |  40    |   60   |   90   |
  A       | 2022-01-05 |  60    |   110  |   100  |
  B       | 2022-01-05 |  70    |   125  |   100  |
  C       | 2022-01-05 |  100   |   105  |   155  |
  A       | 2022-01-10 |  110   |   150  |   135  |
  B       | 2022-01-10 |  120   |   175  |   125  |
  C       | 2022-01-10 |  150   |   200  |   240  |
```

All numerical columns are cumsum (Val1, Val2 & Val3)

I tried to take reference from [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70624797/pandas-groupby-cumulative-sum-and-month) but couldn't make it work in my case.

Comment: Can you explain more how update by date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not groupby by `date`, only by `Category` ouput is:

```
cols = ['Val1','Val2','Val3']
df[cols] = df.groupby('Category')[cols].cumsum()
print (df)
  Category       Date  Val1  Val2  Val3
0        A 2022-01-01    50    70    80
1        B 2022-01-01    30    50    20
2        C 2022-01-01    40    60    90
3        A 2022-01-05    60   110   100
4        B 2022-01-05    70   125   100
5        C 2022-01-05   100   105   155
6        A 2022-01-10   110   150   135
7        B 2022-01-10   120   175   125
8        C 2022-01-10   150   200   240
```

If need also groupby per months and `Category` use:

```
cols = ['Val1','Val2','Val3']
df[cols] = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='M'), 'Category'])[cols].cumsum()
#alternative
#df[cols] = df.groupby([df['Date'].dt.to_period('m'), 'Category'])[cols].cumsum()
print (df)

  Category       Date  Val1  Val2  Val3
0        A 2022-01-01    50    70    80
1        B 2022-01-01    30    50    20
2        C 2022-01-01    40    60    90
3        A 2022-01-05    60   110   100
4        B 2022-01-05    70   125   100
5        C 2022-01-05   100   105   155
6        A 2022-01-10   110   150   135
7        B 2022-01-10   120   175   125
8        C 2022-01-10   150   200   240
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) (on Category only, it doesn't make sense to group by date as each group would be only one value so nothing to cumsum) and [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the DataFrame:

```
df.update(df.groupby(['Category']).cumsum())
```

output

```
  Category        Date  Val1  Val2  Val3
0        A  2022-01-01    50    70    80
1        B  2022-01-01    30    50    20
2        C  2022-01-01    40    60    90
3        A  2022-01-05    60   110   100
4        B  2022-01-05    70   125   100
5        C  2022-01-05   100   105   155
6        A  2022-01-10   110   150   135
7        B  2022-01-10   120   175   125
8        C  2022-01-10   150   200   240
```